# SCAN.UPC: RCurl package doesn't use 64-bit library Rcurl.dll

Tags: r, rstudio, rcurl

I am using updated R-Studio on Win XP-64, with R version 3-1-2, and have all the Bioconductor packages updated.   When loading SCAN.UPC, an exception is thrown by R stating that the 64-bit Rcurl.dll can't be found in the 64-bit Rcurl library.  However, there is a dll in both the 32- and 64-bit ...Rcurl/lib/... folders.  I can also successfully load Rcurl by itself. So the issue is that when SCAN.UPC is loaded, it calls RCurl, and R claims that it can't find the 64-bit dll.  Any suggestions?

Comment: SCAN.UPC doesn't depend or import RCurl directly, but rather through it's dependency on GEOquery. Can you update your question describing the situation when trying to load GEOquery rather than SCAN.UPC? Please also edit your question to include the full output of the command and error message that results, as well as the output of `sessionInfo()` and `.libPaths()` after trying to load the package. Please also try the command BiocInstaller::biocValid(). Finally, consider moving this question to the Bioconductor [support site](https://support.bioconductor.org)

Comment: > library("SCAN.UPC")

Loading required package: GEOquery
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.2/library/RCurl/libs/x64/RCurl.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found.

Error: package ‘GEOquery’ could not be loaded

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED - I uninstalled R-Studio and every old installation of R, and then re-installed R-Studio (which installed R-3.1.2).  After that, there were no issues.